# how to enter values in multiple tables using same id

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 tables
**emp_ref_table**  with fields
1.emp_id(pk,ai)
2.emp_name
3.gender
4.emp_address

**emp_login_table**
1.id(ai,pk)
2.emp_id(fk)
3.Password(default : password)

**emp_value_table**
1.emp_value_id(pk)
2.emp_id(fk)
3.emp_photo
4.emp_resume

I have to insert values in all 3 tables at single time.
Suppose first, i insert value in **emp_ref_table** the emp_id will be generated automatically
after generation of emp_id i have to store that last emp_id in **login_table** also
after login table same emp_id also have to be inserted in **emp_value_table**

i have tried this and its working fine,now get stuck on **emp_value_table**  both queries working absolutely fine now help me in storing the emp_id in emp_value_table

```
insert into emp_ref_table(emp_name,gender,emp_address) values ('xyz','d','abc');
insert into `login_table`(emp_id) values(LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

PS: i'm using stored procedures

Comment: You can make a trigger, so when you insert into one table, it inserts into others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stored procedure declare a variable that will hold the new employee id. After inserting a record into employee reference table, assign the new id to the varible. Use this variable to assign value to employee id fields in the subsequent 2 inserts.

```
...
declare empid int;
insert into emp_ref_table(emp_name,gender,emp_address) values ('xyz','d','abc');
set empid=last_insert_id();
insert into `login_table`(emp_id) values(empid);
...
```